# My ubuntu background is totally black, even after opening programs such as terminal

Tags: ubuntu, unity

My Ubuntu background is totally black when I log in. I can open the terminal, write command so that i open other programs, but I am unable to see any of it.

[image]

Comment: Is this a new installation that has never worked differently, or did this use to work and change overnight without anybody touching anything?

Answer (score 2):

This is Gnome specific fix:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate Ubuntu desktop wallpaper.For this, you have to install `ubuntu-tweak` package,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

After installation of Ubuntu tweak, run it.Using that utility activate your desktop wallpaper.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here

Comment: @Kiwy this type of problem will appear in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in 13.10. To fix it simply enable desktop icons using Ubuntu Tweak tool:

```
Desktop -> Desktop Icons -> Show desktop icons -> On
```

Do not turn off this option! Otherwise you'll get a gui gotchas on minimize window placed right above desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Press Alt-Space to get the window menu. Then you see, if the program startet correctly. You can also choose move and move the window with the arrow keys.
- Press Win-Up to maximize the window. May you see it then.
- Press Alt-F5 to maximize the window. May you see it then.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me in a VM.

I had to right click on the desktop, change background image, close the window, than change back to the original image that was turned black.